# SQL Trigger not working using concat

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "MY_TRIGGER2" 
     BEFORE INSERT ON "FILM" 
     FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
            IF :NEW.RATING = 'G'
                    THEN :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST := :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST - .10
          AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION := CONCAT(:NEW.DESCRIPTION, 'Recommended for all audiences';
                    END IF;
      IF :NEW.RATING = 'PG'
                    THEN :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST := :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST + .20
          AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION := CONCAT(:NEW.DESCRIPTION, 'Parental guidance for young viewers';
                    END IF;
            IF :NEW.RATING = 'PG-13'
                    THEN :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST := :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST + .20
          AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION := CONCAT(:NEW.DESCRIPTION, 'Parental guidance for young viewers';
                    END IF;
      IF :NEW.RATING = 'R'
                    THEN :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST := :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST + .60
          AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION := CONCAT(:NEW.DESCRIPTION, 'Recommnded for mature audiences';
                    END IF;
      IF :NEW.RATING = 'NC-17'
                    THEN :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST := :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST + 1.0
          AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION := CONCAT(:NEW.DESCRIPTION, 'Mature audiences only';
                    END IF; 
    END;
    /
```

I have this but the concat part throws error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, specify what is the error.

Comment: You are not finishing the call with `)`

Answer (score 1):

```
:NEW.DESCRIPTION := CONCAT(:NEW.DESCRIPTION, 'Mature audiences only';
```

I don't see a closing parenthesis on the end<sup>(1)</sup> of that (or any of your other) `concat` lines. That's almost certainly a syntax error.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *Before* the semicolon, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
        IF :NEW.RATING = 'G'
                THEN :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST := :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST - .10
      AND :NEW.DESCRIPTION := CONCAT(:NEW.DESCRIPTION, 'Recommended for all audiences';
                END IF;
```

Is just weird.  In addition to the missing paren, don't use `AND` for assignments.  So:

```
        IF :NEW.RATING = 'G' THEN
            :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST := :NEW.REPLACEMENT_COST - .10;
            :NEW.DESCRIPTION := CONCAT(:NEW.DESCRIPTION, 'Recommended for all audiences');
        END IF;
```

You'll need to fix the rest of your code.